# Post rewrite 404 errors

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I have just completed a rewrite and migration for a platform. The migration was from a static server to Elastic Beanstalk and went very well. Currently, I am experiencing a problem where old URL paths (from emails and such) are causing a lot of 404 errors on my Elastic Beanstalk environment and this is causing health warnings. Can anyone recommend a good way to handle these 404 errors? Maybe through Apache to turn them away properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all 404 to your index page.

In your .htaccess file, put these two lines at the top:

> DirectoryIndex index.html
>
> ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/